# c# no overload for method "method" takes 0 arguments, the name "name" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, xna, xna-4.0

**edit**

now my original problem has been fixed but now I'm just getting "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". after researching this error is apparently what happens when you make an instance of a static function, but my function that i want to call is not static.

**end of edit***

I have scoured the Internet trying to find a solution trying to find a way to fix these errors so my game will work. I'm using the newest version of Microsoft Visual Studio, c#, and XNA 4.0. my problem is on line 146 of Game1.cs i'm trying to reference the Draw method on line 28 of ManageTheseScreens.cs (changed for debug reasons) but i'm getting 2 errors (stated in title). If anyone could please help it would be greatly appreciated, I also apologize if it is a very simple fix and i wasted your time.

```
///this is in Game1.cs

 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
       /*this is how i'm trying to reference the draw method in the other class*/
           ManageTheseScreens.Draw(ActiveScreen);

            spriteBatch.End();


            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
///this is ManageTheseScreens.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

using WindowsGame1.Screens;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    public class ManageTheseScreens
    {
        ArrayList Screens;
        Screen CurrentScreen;

        public ManageTheseScreens()
        {
            Screens = new ArrayList();
            Screens.Add(new TitleScreen());

            CurrentScreen = (Screen)Screens[0];
        }
///this is what i'm trying to reference
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch ActiveScreen)
        {

            CurrentScreen.Draw(ActiveScreen);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code around the line where you are getting this error.

Comment: First, start by pasting the code in your question.  If it's happening in many places, just include a small segment which demonstrates the problem.  Do not link to an external file; we're not going to sift through your code and/or open it ourselves to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: sorry, didn't know what would be easier because the error is in the referencing of the other class.

Answer (score 0):

You never create an instance of 'ManageTheseScreens' which you need to do before you try and invoke methods on it.  This is where your first problem is coming from.

Under `Spritebatch spriteBatch;` on line 33 add the following line:
`ManageTheseScreens manageTheseScreens = new ManageTheseScreens();` What this does is it creates a new instance of the 'ManageTheseScreens' object that you can use.

Then, instead of `ManageTheseScreens.Draw(ActiveScreen);` use `manageTheseScreens.Draw(spriteBatch);` I'm assuming you want to pass a spritebatch in here, based on the code in the 'ManageTheseScreens' class. This is where your second error is coming from, as you have no variable in 'Game1' called 'ActiveScreen.'

The Game1 class should now look like this:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    ManageTheseScreens manageTheseScreens = new ManageTheseScreens();

    int screenWidth;
    int screenHight;

    /// <summary>
    /// StartingLoad from ScreenSwitcher.cs
    /// </summary>
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        this.IsMouseVisible = true;
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Content_Manager.getInstance().loadTextures(Content);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        manageTheseScreens.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

}
```

(I've removed some of the comments and irrelevant functions)

Hope that helps.

Comment: now i get an error that says "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: Whereabouts is the error occurring? Sounds like there's a variable you aren't creating an instance of still.

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I'm guessing the code should look like

Comment: that's exactly what i have. I'm just getting "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". after researching this error is apparently what happens when you make an instance of a static function, but my function that i want to call is not static.